# How to persist background transparency while converting image from png to jpg android?

Tags: android, bitmap

While converting image from png to jpg losing background transparency of png image.How to persist image background in android programmatically?

```
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,fos);
```

Android developer

Answer (score 4):

The JPEG image format doesn't support transparency on backgrounds.

Comment: Atleast tell me how to know the existing image(png only) has persistency color or programmatically